# Wordpress is single undefined

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a new wordpress plugin, which only be displayed in posts, but to detect it's a post, I'm trying to use is_single(), but it does not work.

```
class myplugin{
//my plugin code here
}
function load_plugin($plugin_class, $priority = 10) {
    if (class_exists($plugin_class)) {
        add_action("init",
                create_function('', "global \$$plugin_class; \$$plugin_class = new $plugin_class();"),
                $priority);
    }
}
if(is_single()){  // witout this, the plugin is displayed everywhere, but whit it it's not displayed at all
load_plugin(myplugin);
}
```

I even tried to see the output of is_single

```
echo"<script>alert('".is_single()."');</script>";
```

i get "undefined"

**edit //** witout the is_single and just loading my plugin, my plugin works on every page of wordpress.

Comment: Have you checked error logs? "Not working" doesn't give us much to go on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), like is_single, are not available until the the wp hook has fired. You're trying to use it too early, which is why it returns undefined.

Add your function to a hook after that and do the is_single test there. There is very little overhead in this so don't worry about performance issues.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice that ! Thank you.